# How to get a token passed as header using datasnap?

Tags: delphi, http-headers, firemonkey, indy, datasnap

In my client application I'm using the following code to add a token in the header:

```
RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + MyToken, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [TRESTRequestParameterOption.poDoNotEncode]);
```

I'd like to get this token in my server using datasnap.

I've tried use the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14092079/116875) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8669046/116875) but without success.

Is it possible?

How can I do this?

### EDIT

I could verify that `Datasnap` executes `TIdCustomHTTPServer.DoParseAuthentication`and that `DoParseAuthentication` calls `FOnParseAuthentication` if it is assigned.

**So, how can I hack Datasnap to assign my own `OnParseAuthentication`?**

I think this solve my problem.

Comment: Are you sure the information arrives at the destination, i.e. can you inspect the HTTP coming in?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure @JanDoggen. I can see this information debugging the PreparePostStream Method of the unit IdCustomHTTPServer. It calls the function `TIdCustomHTTPServer.DoParseAuthentication`. And it uses the default parser for the authentication. Maybe I could get the OnParserAuthentication of the IdHttpServer that Datasnap uses inside, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Sorry, I said `PreparePostStream` but it is `TIdCustomHTTPServer.DoExecute` instead

Comment: @DanielGrillo, i have same problem, u resolved?

Comment: @DanielGrillo, se você poder ma ajudar, eu agradeço não estou conseguindo resolver.

Comment: @JeffersonRudolf Faça a pergunta no SO em português que eu respondo lá.

Comment: @DanielGrillom ta certo

Comment: @DanielGrillo, postei a pergunta lá http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168614/como-pegar-request-header-passando-o-authorization-bearer-usando-datasnap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem. if the Authentication header is used then we get EIdHTTPUnsupportedAuthorisationScheme error, I need to setup OnParseAuthentication. I just started looking into this today and in the Test App "Desktop" I can do the following.

```
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FServer := TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.Create(Self);
  FServer.OnParseAuthentication := DoParseAuthentication;// <-added this line
end;
```

Now I need to figure out how to update the ASAPI dll to do the same.

Comment: where DoParseAuthentication? its function protected

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TForm1.DoParseAuthentication(AContext: TIdContext;
  const AAuthType, AAuthData: String; var VUsername, VPassword: String;
  var VHandled: Boolean);
var
  AuthValue: String;
begin
  if SameText(AAuthType, 'Bearer') then
  begin
    // AAuthData should contain the bearer token
    // You should validate the token here and set the VUsername or VPassword
    // to the corresponding values if the token is valid.
    AuthValue := AAuthData;
    
    // Add your token validation logic here. If the token is valid, you could 
    // set VUsername to the corresponding username and VHandled to True.
    
    // Example:
    // if ValidateToken(AuthValue) then
    // begin
    //   VUsername := GetUserNameFromToken(AuthValue);
    //   VHandled := True;
    // end;

    VHandled := True;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).