# How can I get the parameter of a command method inside TDSAutenticationManager.OnUserAuthorize event?

Tags: delphi, authorization, datasnap

Using the parameter `AuthorizeEventObject` I can get the name of the called method using the property `MethodAlias` inside `OnUserAuthorize`.
I'd like to get the parameter(s) of this method.

For example, if `ReverseString` was called, I'd like to get the `Value` parameter inside `OnUserAuthorize`

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is the better way but with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14092079/116875) and [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8669046/116875) I have solved my problem.

```
uses     Web.HTTPApp, Datasnap.DSHTTPWebBroker, IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge;

procedure TServerContainer1.DSAuthenticationManager1UserAuthorize(Sender: TObject; AuthorizeEventObject: TDSAuthorizeEventObject; var valid: Boolean);
var
    Module  : TWebModule;
    MyDesiredParameter: string;
begin
    Module := GetDataSnapWebModule;
    MyDesiredParameter := string(TIdHTTPAppRequest(Module.Request).PathInfo);

    MyDesiredParameter := MyDesiredParameter.Split(['/'])[POSITION_OF_MY_DESIRED_PARAMETER];

    {
      ... 
      MyCode  
      ...
    } 

end;
```