# Header HTTP Origin in TWebRequest

Tags: delphi, cors

How can I get the equivalent of php:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']
```

in delphi?, I'm using **TWebRequest** in a **WebBroker applications project** (not datasnap).

Comment: I think you need GetFieldByName —Request.GetFieldByName('ORIGIN'), where Request is some instance of TWebRequest.

Comment: I also thought the same, I even tried but it did not work. The TWebRequest class has properties for some headers but I did not find any to read 'Origin'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works using `Request.GetFieldByName ('ORIGIN')` where **Request** is some instance of **TWebReques**. However, there are "hidden" headers, to obtain them you can use a solution based on the response of the following link: [Enumerate TWebRequest HTTP header fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666411/enumerate-twebrequest-http-header-fields), and save them in a TDictionary

Comment: Request.GetFieldByName ('ORIGIN')  works for me with Delphi 11 in August 2022.
Note that the beginning of the origin will be 'http://' or 'https://' so you may need to strip that off before deciding whether to allow access from the particular domain name.