# Delphi Datasnap REST Read Request Header TWebrequest

Tags: rest, delphi, header

I have a datasnap REST server that receives trafic from webhook or client. Incoming request contains header fields, with tokens, I need to access to auth the user request.

I use the following method to do some processing.

procedure TWebModule1.WebModuleBeforeDispatch(Sender: TObject;
Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin

How can I access the incoming header tokens

Tokens passed for example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I modified the below: Delphi 10.4
[Enumerate TWebRequest HTTP header fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666411/enumerate-twebrequest-http-header-fields)

```
uses
IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge,IdCustomHTTPServer;

type
  TIdHTTPAppRequestHelper =  class helper for TIdHTTPAppRequest
  public
    function GetRequestInfo : TIdHTTPRequestInfo;
  end;

implementation

function TIdHTTPAppRequestHelper.GetRequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo;
begin
  Result := FRequestInfo;
end;

procedure TWebModule1.WebModuleBeforeDispatch(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  lString : String;
begin
  //code is the header, lstring is the value  
  lString := TIdHTTPAppRequest(Request).GetRequestInfo.RawHeaders.Values['code'];
end;
```